# Help Identifying a Voltage Regulator 0 - 5 Volt?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-source

So this voltage regulator came from a variable resistor for my 06 Infinity QX56 AC blower motor. I have already replaced the unit with a new one but figured I would try to fix this and have a spare. Well the voltage regulater cracked in half and is somewhat unidentifiable to me.

The only info I can provide about its output is that it should be able to provide a 0 - 5 volt.

[image: cracked voltage regulator]

Any help in figuring this out is most appreciated.

Comment: I assume you can't make out the part number on it?

Comment: @Felthry exactly i can see a 55-08

Comment: Are there any recognisable logos visible?

Comment: Even better, can you open up the new one and see what part is in that spot?

Comment: @Felthry no just the beginning of a ph it looks like

Comment: @Felthry in fact I can when the wife brings car back. One question though should it be the same  even though different manufacturer

Comment: Get your camera to focus on the number and not the table or metal tab. My eyes want to see a "3" just before the N (I think it is one) but it could be a "2". The letter/digit just before the "55" is probably important to work out. Do you have a jeweler's lens (or coin lens?) No idea what starts with "PH" but certainly a lot of parts start with "PN", if that's possible, though I can't recall seeing it on a TO-220 package, or similar.

Comment: @jonk That is the best the camera will do. I think its an N as well i do have a jewelers lens and cant figure out what it is before the n i stared at it for about an hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think it's a voltage regulator?  Could it be one of these...

[image: mosfet]

with a data sheet [here](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/24515/STMICROELECTRONICS/STP80NF55-08.html).  Says its for automotive environments.  Would this make any sense?

Comment: Actually i thought maybe a mosfet or possibly something else but in my mind the best thing was the voltage regulator. I think this may be it i will read specs now thank you for this

Comment: It may be the pass element of a larger regulator circuit though.

Comment: Not only does the part name match perfectly, and the manufacturer's logo, but that seems to be a bead on the gate as well, again suggesting MOSFET not regulator.

Comment: I actually just ordered the mosfet from amazon. I will try it then supply a low input voltage to i get an ouput and see what I get. Ill let you know if i fry the circuit or not but I think this is right. Or ill just check the new one before actually putting it in

Comment: Keep forgetting to update this. Yes this was the mosfet. I replaced it and now have a spare variable resistor for my truck. Thank you very much